# Get videos from youtube api from channel returns Device Support video Url only

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, youtube

I am getting videos from a youtube channel in my asp.net web application. but It is returning the id of only one video saying

> Youtube is upgrading which is not supported by this device or app.
>   The Url of video is-[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKY3scPIMd8)

my code to get videos from channel is-

```
 public static DataTable GetVideos(int maxElements)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("VideoId");
        dt.Columns.Add("UploadedDate");
        dt.Columns.Add("author");
        dt.Columns.Add("content");
        dt.Columns.Add("viewCount");
        YouTubeRequestSettings settings =
        new YouTubeRequestSettings(YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, key);
        settings.Maximum = maxElements;
        settings.PageSize = 1000;
        settings.AutoPaging = true;
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
        string feedUrl = String.Format
        ("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads?orderby=published", YOUTUBE_CHANNEL);


        Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

        foreach (var video in videoFeed.Entries)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Title"] = video.Title;
            dr["VideoId"] = video.VideoId;
            dr["UploadedDate"] = video.Updated;
            dr["author"] = video.Author;
            dr["viewCount"] = video.ViewCount;
            dr["content"] = video.Contents.ToString();

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the old gdata call, which is deprecated. As of 2015-05-06, you must use the v3 calls. Google has a helpful(ish) migration section on the developer site- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#search

I'm actually going through the exact same process myself. I'll post more here once I find a decent solution.